# Functional calculation for Hermitian matrices

Tags: random-matrices

First, let me recall some useful definitions

We recall that if $A=U \Lambda U^*$ is a Hermitian matrix with $U U^*=U^* U=I$ and $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}\left(\lambda_1\right)$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function then the matrix $f(A)$ is defined by
$$
f(A)=U \operatorname{diag}\left(f\left(\lambda_i\right)\right) U^{*}
$$

If $f$ is further differentiable, then
$$
\operatorname{Tr} f(A+H)=\operatorname{Tr} f(A)+\operatorname{Tr}\left(f^{\prime}(A) H\right)+o(\|H\|), \quad H \in \mathcal{H}_n .
$$

**My problem**
Let $f, g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two continuous continuous functions with compact support. We consider the Hermitian matrices $f\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ and $g\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$.

We will fix that $k\in [n]$ and $k \le l$. I want to identify constant $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\gamma$  such that

\begin{aligned}
& \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{k k}}\left\{\operatorname{Tr} f\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right\}=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{n}}\left[f^{\prime}\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right]_{k k} \\
& \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{k \ell}}\left\{\operatorname{Tr} f\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right\}=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{n}}\left[f^{\prime}\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right]_{\ell k}\\
& \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{X_{k \ell}}}\left\{\operatorname{Tr} f\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right\}=\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{n}}\left[f^{\prime}\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right]_{k\ell}
\end{aligned}

I tried to take values of $H$ and use the above formula but I can't obtain the result. Could you please help me with this problem?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The $\sqrt{n}$ factors can be absorbed in the $X$ matrices, I can omit them. Consider a Hermitian matrix $X$ and a Hermitian perturbation $\delta X$. Then, for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ one has
$$\operatorname{Tr}f(X+\delta X)=\sum_{i}f(X)_{ii}+\sum_{i}f'(X)_{ii}\delta X_{ii}+\sum_{i<j}\left[f'(X)_{ji}\delta X_{ij}+\overline{f'(X)}_{ji}\overline{\delta X}_{ij}\right]+{\cal O}(\delta X)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}}\operatorname{Tr}f(X)=\begin{cases}f'(X)_{ii}&\text{if}\;\;i=j\\
f'(X)_{ji}&\text{if}\;\;i< j,\end{cases}$$
and also
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{X}_{ij}}\operatorname{Tr}f(X)=\overline{f'(X)}_{ji}=f'(X)_{ij}.$$
So $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are all equal to 1.

Comment: Hello, 
I also add the new problem. Could you please help me with taking a look on that problem?

Comment: And what do you mean by $\delta X$ ?

Comment: $\delta X$ is a Hermitian perturbation of $X$; I have rewritten the answer for complex $X$.

Comment: Could you please explain why you obtain $\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}}\operatorname{Tr}f(X)=\begin{cases}f'(X)_{ii}&\text{if}\;\;i=j\\
f'(X)_{ji}&\text{if}\;\;i< j,\end{cases}$

Comment: you can read it off from the first equation that I wrote down: for a single variable you have $f(x+\delta x)=f(x)+f'(x)\delta x +{\cal O}(\delta x)^2$, so the coefficient that multiplies $\delta x$ gives you the derivative with respect to $x$; here you apply that to the coefficient that multiplies $\delta X_{ii}$, to find the derivative with respect to $X_{ii}$, and similarly for the derivative with respect to an off-diagonal element.

Comment: Many thanks. Have a nice day